# How to distinguish between license for code and license for dataset within an R package?

Tags: r, package

I am building an R package which contains both lines of code and a dataset. Is it possible to have one license for code and another license for the dataset? How to specify this properly?

Comment: How important is the dataset to the package? I recommend trying to keep everything as open as possible if you're releasing a package.

Comment: One simple and clear way to separate would be to make two packages - one with code and its license, and another package just with data and its license. The code package can depend on the data package, and there will be much less chance for confusion about licenses.

Comment: Another advantage of Gregor's approach is that most likely the code changes more often than the data so when updates do occur the size of the downloads can be smaller.